# How to change EditText hint in main context with AlertDialog

Tags: android

```
private EditText result = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
final String[] dropdownList ={"a123", "b456"};

public void onCreate(...) {
    ...
    alert();
}


private void alert() {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    .setTitle("select")
    .setSingleChoiceItems(dropdownList, checkedItem, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    result.setHint("some tips");
                }
        )}.show()
```

EditText result is already have a hint in layout.xml, but I want to change the hint in

EditText result, but the code above throws a NullPointerException, what's the problem?

edit:

```
public class AAA extends Activity {

private EditText result;
private String[] dropdownList = {"A123", "A456"};
private int checkedItem = 0; 

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    result = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    alert();
}

private void alert() {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    .setTitle("select")
    .setSingleChoiceItems(dropdownList, checkedItem, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    result.setHint("some tips");
                }
    }).show();
}
```

}

Comment: Where is your `setContentView(...)`

Comment: contentView is not the point, i just want to know how to change hint in AlterDialog

Comment: Can you give me a sample to use handler to change the hint?

Comment: if `private EditText result = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);` is outside onCreate Method of Activity then Plz put it inside onCreate after `setContentView(...)`

Comment: i did, also throws a NullPointerException

Comment: can you post the modified code? it shouldn't throw null pointer after doing what @imrankhan suggested.

Comment: If answers have already helped you, please help the users by marking the question as answered, so that people providing solutions don't have to look into the questions again and again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a handler to update any UI component from an alertDialog.

```
Handler handler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
       result.setHint("some tips");
    }
}

private void alert() {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle("select")
    .setSingleChoiceItems(dropdownList, checkedItem, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
        }
    }).show();
}
```